# How do I console.log state.car.price in my reducer function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I can't seem to access a property that's nested within an object. I want to have my app up and running but I cannot get passed this bug.

```
const initialState = {
  additionalPrice: 0,
  title:"hi",
    car: {
      price: 26395,
      name: '2019 Ford Mustang',
      image:
        'https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/0AN2V/s1/2019-ford-mustang-bullitt.jpg',
      features: []
    },
    additionalFeatures: [
      { id: 1, name: 'V-6 engine', price: 1500 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Racing detail package', price: 1500 },
      { id: 3, name: 'Premium sound system', price: 500 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Rear spoiler', price: 250 }
    ]
};

export const featuresReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action, state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FEATURE:
      return {
        ...state,
       ...state.car:{...state.car:price:5}
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
  console.log(state.car.price)
};
```

Comment: You're looking for `state.car.title.price` :)

Comment: Have you tried putting console.log before return?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling featuresReducer? If you're only passing one parameter, it would go in the `state` variable, and if you pass it two variables, it would overwrite the `initialState` default.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning in the switch statement before the console.log is executed. Also I think you have a ":" where you meant to use a ",".Try something like this:

```
export const featuresReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action, state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FEATURE:
      console.log("here");
      return {
        ...state,
        car: { ...state.car, price: 5 }
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

If you want to see the state.car.price you'll have to call console.log after the reducer action is performed.

Comment: Can you give more information than "this doesn't work"? What error are you seeing?

Comment: @tgmarcus I updated the code to try to fix a potential error.